# Cannot view asset in workflow liferay

Tags: java, liferay, liferay-6

I created a portlet with workflow on liferay portal CE 6.2.0 and added single approver workflow to it after deployment. It works successfully and i can view notification, assign to someone and approve it or reject. But when I click on view button it says "asset not found"
[image]

---

I couldn't figure out what I missed. I have the following in my code.

In LocalServiceImpl

```
assetEntryLocalService.updateEntry(userId, timesheet.getGroupId(),
                date, date, Timesheet.class.getName(),
                timesheet.getPrimaryKey(), timesheet.getUuid(), 0,
                serviceContext.getAssetCategoryIds(),
                serviceContext.getAssetTagNames(), true, null, null, null,
                null, ContentTypes.TEXT_HTML, timesheet.getProject(),
                timesheet.getTaskType(), timesheet.getProject() + " : "
                        + timesheet.getTaskType(), null, 0, 0, 0, false);
```

In AssetRenderer

```
public String render(RenderRequest request, RenderResponse response,
        String template) throws Exception {
    if (template.equals("full_content")) {
        request.setAttribute("TIMESHEET_ENTRY", _timesheet);
        return "/html/" + template + ".jsp";
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

In AssetRendererFactory

```
public AssetRenderer getAssetRenderer(long classPK, int type)
        throws PortalException, SystemException {
    Timesheet timesheet = TimesheetLocalServiceUtil.getTimesheet(classPK);
    return new TimesheetAssetRenderer(timesheet);
}
```

Is there anything wrong in what I am doing?

I had added the following in my portlet.xml

```
        <asset-renderer-factory>com.timesheet.asset.TimesheetAssetRendererFactory</asset-renderer-factory>
```

Is it some other function that i need to override?

I found that the error is thrown from  liferay-portal / portal-web / docroot / html / portlet / asset_publisher / view_content.jsp at the below given code point

```
if (!assetEntry.isVisible() &&
            (assetRenderer.getAssetRendererType() == AssetRendererFactory.TYPE_LATEST_APPROVED)) {

            throw new NoSuchModelException();
    }
```

Here I could find that even if I set visible to true in my updateEntry method call, it is being set to false. I dont know what to do for this. Where is the problem happening?

Comment: Any error or message in log?

Comment: no. No errors in the console. All I can get is this error in the UI.

Comment: But I strongly believe that I am missing something, because I just took tutorials and followed them and had lot of errors mostly solved by myself. Is the above code all that we need to add as an asset?

Comment: Can you check that your -virtual host- matches the -url- you are using when you're testing the site ?

Comment: Welcome to Liferay development :-) Just to be constructive: have you tried debugging the `view_content.jsp` of Asset Publisher? Are you sure the visibility is `true` and not a cached result? What is the value returned by `getAssetRendererType()`?

Comment: I just tried setting it in DB, then everything works fine. This visible being false seems to be the only issue. HELP!!

Comment: Maybe you are doing something wrong in the  updateEntry function you said you override. can you post the code for this function ?

Comment: Here I have updated in the question itself. In LocalServiceImpl.

Comment: Sorry, did I say override? I didn't do anything of that sort. I just did the above call. When I said full signature, I meant method call to full signature method.

Comment: @yannicuLar any idea what is happening?

Comment: Could you please be more clear? @yannicuLar I din't get the above comment

Comment: Just a thought but this could be a missing 'update()' call. This is needed to Let the actual database update the Entry with the new data. Can you try something like AssetEntryLocalServiceUtil.(assetEntry,  false), right after setting 'visible = true'

Comment: Oh Thankyou so much @yannicuLar I replaced assetEntryLocalService with  AssetEntryLocalServiceUtil and the whole problem I had for past three days is solved. Could you post this as an answer? And why does it not work with the object and works fine with Util class?

Comment: I'm glad that worked out. my first bounty yeah! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(porting my comment as an Answer:)

AssetEntry belongs to the Liferay's architecture that uses the Service builder ORM implementation. If you open the Liferay source and search for any [SOME_MODEL_CLASS]LocalServiceImpl Class, you can see the update-type functions are following this pattern:

```
    SOME_MODEL_CLASS obj = sOME_MODEL_CLASSPersistence.findByPrimaryKey(longId);
    obj.setSomeProperty(someValue);
    sOME_MODEL_CLASSPersistence.update(obj, false);
```

Notice that in the end, they are calling the persistence.update, which will eventually store that change in your database.

As a rule, when updating a Liferay Object's value, make sure to call SOME_MODEL_CLASSLocalServiceUtil.update() function. For Example, in the following code, I'm trying to update a user's Facebook id:

```
Contact cnt =  user.getContact();
cnt.setFacebookSn(facebookId);
ContactLocalServiceUtil.updateContact(cnt);
UserLocalServiceUtil.updateUser(user);
```

Comment: Could you please tell why(for what use) we have an object assetEntryLocalService in our *LocalServiceBaseImpl or is it not for the user?

Comment: I really did not understand that. what do you mean 'is it not for the user'

Comment: wait, why are you working with LocalServiceBaseImpl instead of LocalServiceImpl ?

Comment: I used LocalServiceImpl only. But the problem that happened was, in BaseImpl there is an object of assetEntryLocalService already defined, with which I called the method instead of calling using Util. My foolishness. Still a doubt on the purpose of that object defined there.

Comment: Yes, it's a complex architecture. LocalServiceBaseImpl is just a container for LocalServiceImpl. You are supposed to modify the  LocalServiceImpl, and after building, your functions will be exposed to your clients through LocalServiceUtil. In your case, your code was the client, so you were meant to work with *LocalServiceUtil